# Mixing a SQL Server Project and in Business project code first for EF Core - what is the prescribed way to do CI/CD?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, continuous-integration, ef-code-first

I have a project that started simply enough with EF Core code first. I would create migrations and apply them with `dotnet database update` - I even have CI/CD apply the migrations to the prod DB once merged into the `main` branch.

Overtime however, the database complexity increased; views, stored procedures and functions were created to handle some cases that perform much better by remaining on SQL Server. The problem is the tables are now tracked in a SQL Server .NET Core project as well as in the the code first classes in the business layer of the app. With multiple developers, there is a path that a change made in one project is not reflected in the other. Policy and code reviews are the only gates we have.

What is the recommended approach here? I am currently of the opinion that since we have complex SQL objects such as views, stored procedures, function, etc... that we should treat the SQL Server Project as the source of truth and scaffold the EF classes but that fundamentally, the source of truth should be the SQL Server project and its changes should be applied to the database using Flyway or LiquidBase.

Comment: I have OSS tools to generate EF Core DbContext and classes from a .dacpac / Database Project - that would be my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @ErikEJ - when you said you have OSS tools - you meant YOU them - that's awesome, definitely checking this out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Code First design workflow is inappropriate when the database has significant SQL artifacts other than tables, or when the database design is performed by team members without .NET and EF expertise.